# How do I make a button with an Image in flutter that highlights while someone is pressing it?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a button that has an image as  as a child. I want it so that while the button is being pressed, the image changes to a different one, and when the user stops pressing the button, it goes back to its original image.

Basically I want it to act like a raised button but with custom images for the raised and pressed states.

Here's the relevant code:

```
class LoginButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginButtonState createState() => new _LoginButtonState();
}

class _LoginButtonState extends State<LoginButton> {
  void _onClicked() {
    setState(() {
      //I don't know what I should put here to cause the image to redraw 
      //only on button press

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var assetImage = new AssetImage("assets/loginscreen/btn.png");
    var image = new Image(image: assetImage, height: 50.0, width: 330.0);
    return new Container(
      height: image.height,
      width: image.width,
      child: new FlatButton(
        onPressed: _onClicked,
        child: new ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: image,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with more relevant code to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your default image as a property of the class `_LoginButtonState`like this

```
class _LoginButtonState extends State<LoginButton> {
String _myImage = "assets/loginscreen/btn.png"; ... }
```

Now your `_onClick` method should contain the change of the state, simply you can change the string of `_myImage` to the new image using an if condition

```
    void _onClicked() {
        setState(() {
          if (_myImage == "assets/loginscreen/btn.png"){
            _myImage = "<my new asset>";   //change myImage to the other one
             }   
          else {
                 _myImage = "assets/loginscreen/btn.png"; //change myImage back to the original one
                }
        });
      }
```

and within your widget build:

```
var assetImage = new AssetImage(_myImage);
```

**===========================================================================**

**Update**

I have managed to do a similar idea to what you are trying to achieve using `GesutureDetector` , here I tested it with colors, but it should not be so different from changing a link of an image, although I presume repainting an image would be slower than changing colors.

Here is the full code I used:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp (),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _myColor = Colors.blue;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text ("Tap me!"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: new GestureDetector(
        onTapDown:(TapDownDetails details) { setState(() {
      _myColor = Colors.orange;
    });
        },
        onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
          setState(() {
            _myColor = Colors.blue;
          });
        },

        child: new Container (
          color: _myColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I noticed an update in the post after I posted this answer, I am not sure what you mean by changes back when unpressed ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want the image to redraw during press only, and change back to the original image when the button isn't being pressed anymore

Comment: I am trying to simulate a regular button when looks pressed when somone is pressing it, and goes back to its unpressed state when let somone is no longer pressing it

Comment: I am not sure if what you are looking for is an onPressed action, I think we are talking here about listening to the user's touch on top of the button. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html

Comment: Ahh I think this might be it. Do you know where I can find an example of listeners being used? I kinda find it hard to wrap my head around this

Comment: Try to check the sample code in GestureDetector 
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

I have not tried this before so I will give it a try as well.

Comment: Hey @aziza, thanks for your solution, hover there is one specific and annoying problem. I notice that a widget with a Listener or GestureDetector has a slight delay in redrawing when the very first tap on the widget occurs, whereas with subsequent taps this delay doesn't occur. You can reproduce it by restarting your app and tapping the widget again. It doesn't seem to be limited to your app, but to any usage of Listener or Gesture Detector. This is a big issue for me because it makes button look laggy. Especially when buttons are intended to only be clicked once (e.g. a login button)

Comment: Perhaps rather than trying to redraw the widget upon tapDown, do you know if one could implement an animation to the button widget, or an inkwell?  These might be potential solutions but I can't seem to find any good example of their usage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153674/discussion-between-aziza-and-shazamo-morebucks).

Answer (score 1):

For me i wanted a button with no extra padding and would be darken when i press it!
Here is the code that work for me:

```
  Container(
            height: image.height,
            width: image.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('/images/image.jpeg'),
              ),
            ),
            child: new FlatButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: null),
          ),
```

Credits to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ze-BZBv85Ck! This video help me for this! :)